# Torsion elements in $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q^a /\mathbb Q) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

How to find non trivial torsion elements in $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb  Q^a /\mathbb Q) $? One element will be conjugation, but is there any other non trivial torsion element? (Here $\mathbb  Q^a$ denotes the algebraic closure of $\mathbb  Q$.)

Comment: I assume $Q$ is the rationals, but what is $Q^a$?

Comment: Algebraic Closure of Q.

Comment: Using Artin Schreier Theorem, can I say Algebraic Closure of Q is Q(i) hence, Gal group contains only two elements, identity and conjugation?

Comment: No. Q(i) is not algebraically closed. What you can say based on the Artin-Schreier-theorem is that any torsion element of $Gal( \mathbb Q^a /\mathbb Q)$ has an order $\leq 2$.

Comment: So, that makes only non trivial torsion elements are of order 2, and conjugates of conjugation..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma$ be a torsion element of $Gal( \mathbb Q^a /\mathbb Q)$, that is it generates a finite subgroup $G$. Let $F$ be the fixed field of this group. Then $\mathbb{Q}^a/F$ is finite, hence is of degree $2$ by the Artin-Schreier-theorem. So $\sigma$ has order $2$.

Note that every conjugate of an element of order $2$ has order $2$. So the question arises whether two elements of order $2$ are conjugate, and thus whether the torsion elements are precisely the conjugates of complex conjugation.

Comment: does this imply only one torsion element exits or I am wrong?

Comment: The argument does not imply that the only automorphism of order $2$ is complex conjugation.

Comment: Dear @Hagen, Regarding the question you mention at the end, this is true: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138168/embeddings-of-overline-mathbfq-into-mathbfc?lq=1